# calculating REST API test coverage

Tags: java, api-design, test-coverage, jersey-test-framework

Assuming I have a of REST API methods and a set of jersey-test based tests supposedly covering them what is the way to calculate the percentage of API methods covered by those tests?

By test covering the API method I mean it hits the path of that API.

For unit test coverage we currently use JaCoCo but I don't see how it can be applicable for the problem at hand.

By now I'm thinking of parsing jersey logs or something similar but there's probably more established ways of doing this.